# Cloudera CDH 5.7.2 / HBase: How to Set hfile.format.version?

Tags: hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hfile

With CDH 5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.po.18, I am trying to use Cloudera Manager to configure HBase to use visibility labels and authorizations, as described in the Cloudera Community post below:

[Cloudera Manager Hbase Visibility Labels](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Cloudera-Manager-Hbase-Visibility-Labels/td-p/51394)

Using Cloudera Manager, I have successfully updated the values of the following properties:

- hbase.coprocessor.region.classes: Set to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.VisibilityController
- hbase.coprocessor.master.classes: Set to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.VisibilityController
- hbase.security.authorization: Set to true

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, Cloudera Manager doesn't expose the hfile.format.version variable, so I am unable to set it to 3.

When I restart HBase after updating only the three aforementioned variables, errors such as the following appear in the role log:

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.CoprocessorHost: The coprocessor org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.VisibilityController threw java.lang.RuntimeException: A minimum HFile version of 3 is required to persist security labels. Consider setting hfile.format.version accordingly.

I'd love to set hfile.format.version accordingly, but... how would I do that, when it's not exposed in Cloudera Manager? For example, is there some config file on the file system that I can modify? Cloudera Manager has to be getting the current settings from somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera Manager has a configuration section it calls the *Safety Valve* for exactly this purpose.  It will let you set arbitrary properties to whatever value you need.  See [this doc](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_garbage_collection.html) for the following example:

1. Go to the HBase service.
2. Click the Configuration tab.
3. Select Scope > RegionServer.
4. Select Category > Advanced.
5. Locate the HBase Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hbase-site.xml property, or search for it by typing its name in the Search box.
6. Add your custom XML (e.g.):

   `<property>
     <name>property-name</name>
     <value>property-value</value>
    </property>`

Comment: Thank you! FYI under Scope > RegionServer, I found "RegionServer Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hbase-site.xml". Under Scope > Master, I found "Master Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hbase-site.xml". Under Scope > HBase (Service-Wide), I found "HBase Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hbase-site.xml". I assume I should change the last of the three.

Comment: I wound up setting hfile.format.version under (via Scope > HBase (Service-Wide)) "HBase Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hbase-site.xml". HBase restarted with no errors of the kind that I had seen before. I think this was indeed the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @DynothermConnector, don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.