# How to Access HBase Shell As Superuser? (Pre-Configured VM with CDH 5.7.2, HBase 1.2)

Tags: java, shell, hbase, admin

I'm using a pre-configured VM that runs Cloudera CDH 5.7.2 and HBase 1.2. Through Cloudera Manager, [I recently configured HBase to perform authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958309/cloudera-cdh-5-7-2-hbase-how-to-set-hfile-format-version); however, now I need to create an HBase user with sufficient permission to create a table, perform puts/deletes/scans against the table, and then delete the table.

I learned how to access the HBase shell; however, I've just been typing *hbase shell* at the command line, which causes me to access it as the VM's currently authenticated user (root), and the VM's user lacks permission to grant the permissions that I need to associate with a particular HBase user, create the HBase user, etc.

How would I open an HBase shell as HBase's superuser? (I'm not 100% sure who the HBase superuser might be, since the VM was pre-configured.)

I feel like this should be similar to accessing Oracle SQLPLUS, first by authenticating to the machine, and then supplying Oracle user credentials to SQLPLUS to authenticate to Oracle as a sufficiently privileged user.

(I apologize in advance for this HBase rookie-level question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to write to the HDFS path /hbase you need to find out who owns that file.

```
# hdfs dfs -ls /
...
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase supergroup          0 2017-07-14 07:48 /hbase
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs  supergroup          0 2017-07-14 07:48 /tmp
....
```

Most likely it is the service user `hbase`. If it is, then run as `hbase` using sudo.

```
# sudo -u hbase hbase shell
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, the owner of /hbase was indeed the service user _hbase_. I ran the command `sudo -u hbase hbase shell`, as you suggested, and I accessed the HBase shell as the _hbase_ user. Thanks again!